# Piping to "type" command

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I want to find out the type of several commands. Is it possible to pipe or `xargs` a search result from `find` into the `type` command in Linux?

For example:

```
find . -name anacron | type
```

or

```
find . -name anacron | xargs type
```

Comment: I think that Oli answer is the best answer. Chaos answer just works, but Oli answer is clever.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`type` is not a normal command. It's a shell buitin. See:

```
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
```

So, you need to invoke `bash` with `-c` to achieve what you want

```
$ find . -name anacron | xargs -I '{}'  bash -c "type {}"
```

Or even simpler (no need for `xargs`):

```
$ find . -name anacron -exec bash -c "type {}"  \;
```

It will call `bash -c "type ./file"`, with every file that is found by `find`. `-I` in `xargs` means, we define here a placeholder `{}` to use later. This placeholder is replaced with the filename found.

**Why shell builtins don't work with `xargs`:**

> [...] Builtin commands are contained within the shell itself. When the name
>   of a builtin command is used as the first word of a simple command,
>   the shell executes the command directly, without invoking another
>   program. [...]

---

> xargs reads items from the standard input, [...], and executes the
>   command

The command in this case is a simple excutable, and a shell builtin is not an executable. It cannot be found in the filesystem. It's within the shell itself. So you have to call the shell and tell the called shell to invoke the builtin command. That's what happend with `bash -c "command"`.

Comment: You could condense it to `find ... -exec bash -c 'type "$@"' _ {} +`

Comment: @muru indeed, I read my own answer again and saw it =)

Answer (score 11):

There are a few problems here (some already highlighted):

- `type` is a builtin. It's not a command that's resolved, it's a function inside bash. See `man bash-builtins`. It only works in the context of bash so not an `xargs` or `-exec` forked subshell.
- `type` is used to doing its own path searching. If you give it a path (as `find` is wont to do), it'll probably just return that path. `readlink -f` might be better if you're just trying to resolve symlinks; and you can pipe into `xargs readlink` or `-exec readlink -f {} +` all day long.

That's not to say you can't do what you're trying to. There are two options. The `type` command can handle many names at once so you could just provide it all the names at once:

```
type $(find /usr/sbin -name anacron)
```

For many commands, if there are too many arguments you'll exceed the command line length limit (see `getconf ARG_MAX`).  However, that won't apply in this case since `type` is built into the shell and doesn't generate a new process ID (the length limit applies to the *exec()* function used by the child process in a normal command line).

Comment: Thank you Oli! This linux newbie has learned something new today regarding about "type" and its behaviors.